# How to automatically fill textarea with value from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, google-app-engine

I'm making a page for editing an existing document.

The html:

```
<form method="post">

    <div>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder = "title" value="{{title}}">
    </div>
    <br>

    <div>
    <textarea type="text" name="note" class = "textarea" value="{{note}}" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <br>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button span").html("{{note}}");
    });
    </script>

    <div><input type="submit" class = "button"value="okay!"></div>
    <br>
    <div class = "stat">{{stat}}</div>

</form>
```

I read somewhere that textarea doesn't have a working value attribute, so I tried out the jQuery, which doesn't work either. When the page renders, the textarea is blank. Yet when I went into the source code, the value shows up in both the textarea attribute and the jQuery note value! Except all the new lines are replaced by

```
&lt;br&gt;
```

And the note itself is not automatically displayed in the textarea when the page renders. How can I make the note value automatically display in the textarea?

Comment: <textarea>{{note}}</textarea>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the value of textarea a content, like

```
<textarea type="text" name="note" class = "textarea" cols="50" rows="10">{{note}}</textarea>
```

Comment: Oh haha just realized that myself :'D